# Как устанить ошибку CORS?

Tags: php, reactjs, cors

Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на CORS preflight). Код состояния: 400.
Frontend: React, Backend: PHP
В PHP файле отдающем json прописаны все заголовки:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

Но Frontend ругается на cors. Как исправить backend чтобы cors post запросы отправлял?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Backend размещен на хостинге. На субдомене опубликовал свое приложение, все равно ругается на cors

Comment: В консоли браузера

Comment: Заголовки какого запроса показаны на скриншоте? В тексте написано «Код состояния: 400», но на скриншоте никакого 400 не видно

Comment: Но вообще сам код 400 может косвенно намекать на то, что на бэкенде некорректно реализована (или вообще не реализована) обработка preflight OPTIONS-запроса

Comment: Как её реализовать?

Comment: конфиг ngnix либо .htaccess если апач. там пропишите.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
или
конфиг ngnix либо .htaccess если апач. там пропишите